# Android 4.0 ActivityGroup and FrameLayout Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, activitygroup

I have an app that uses an ActivityGroup and FrameLayout to show activities and tabs.
Everything works fine on devices pre android 4.0. 
However, when using a device with 4.x the tabs are not showing. It's just a gray area.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? I know that ActivityGroup is deprecated, but it should still be working on > 4.0 right? Or do you have to do it in another way? (the app is not worth changing everything to fragments)

I've included screens that shows what I mean.

Thanks!
-Rob!

**Edit;** The app is using TabHost and TabWidget for this purpose. I didn't really clarify that.

[pre android 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaDxK.jpg)

[post android 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crtdr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you who are interested, I found a solution to my problem.

In the `TabWidget` class (which extends `LinearLayout`) I removed the overriding of the `setDividerDrawable()` method. For some reason this method wasn't even called when running on devices < 4.0, thus having no impact on the application. But when running the app on a 4.0+ this method was called, and the divider was basically not set and the whole `TabWidget` got screwed up.

Why this happens I have no idea, so if anyone knows why, please feel free to enlighten the rest of us :)

Hope this will help someone else too.

Cheers!